# Matrix Square Root with complex eigenvectors and eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

> Note: The programming language that I'm trying to implement this
> algorithm in doesn't support **Complex** datatype so it should be
> noted that I have to handle the **Real** and **Imaginary** parts
> separately. I can't use any built-in libraries and I have to make this algorithm with pure mathematical steps.

Suppose we have a matrix

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

I want to calculate the square root of this matrix. For this purpose, we have to calculate the **eigenvalues** and **eigenvectors**. In this case, we get

$$
eigenvalues = \begin{bmatrix}1+1j&1-1j\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
eigenvectors = \begin{bmatrix}0.70710678+0j&0.70710678-0j\\0-0.70710678j&0+0.70710678j\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now as we know that the square root of the matrix can be calculated as

$$PD^{1/2}P^{-1}$$

Now keeping this diagram in mind
[image: ComplexTree]

and by evaluating

$$
P_r = \begin{bmatrix}0.70710678&-0.70710678\\0&0\end{bmatrix} 
$$
$$
P_i = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\-0.70710678&0.70710678\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
D_{rr} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
D_{ri} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
D_{ir} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
D_{ii} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

The problem is that there are a total of 8 equations that can be formed from it if we consider the **real** part and **complex** part separately which are as follows

$$
P_r * D_{rr} * P_r^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$P_r * D_{ri} * P_r^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$P_r * D_{ir} * P_r^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}0.5&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$P_r * D_{ii} * P_r^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}0.5&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$P_i * D_{rr} * P_i^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$P_i * D_{ri} * P_i^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$P_i * D_{ir} * P_i^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0.5\end{bmatrix}$$

$$P_i * D_{ii} * P_i^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0.5\end{bmatrix}$$

The expected output of the square root of matrix **A** is

$$real = \begin{bmatrix}1.09868411&-0.45508986\\0.45508986&1.09868411\end{bmatrix}$$

$$imaginary = \begin{bmatrix}-5.55111512e^{-17}&1.11022302e^{-16}\\0.00000000e^{+00}&2.77555756e^{-17}\end{bmatrix}$$

**Question**

1. Am I on the right track? If not, what is the right direction?
2. If I'm on the right track, how can I use these equations to generate the expected results? It would be great if I can get a single derived equation.

Comment: What programming language is it? Can't you define a class for complex numbers? That would be clearer. Also, every nonzero complex number have 2 square roots, so the square root of $A$ is not unique.

Comment: @Berci The programming language is not of concern over here. It can be any language. I'm just trying to understand that how can I evaluate this by handling real and imaginary parts separately. I'm trying to develop this in Swift Language. I have created an algorithm that works great if my eigenvalues and eigenvectors are not in complex domain. But the algorithm breaks when eigens are in complex domain and I don't know how to handle that.

Comment: @Berci I know Swift supports Complex Datatype. I'm just having a hard time figuring out that how can I use complex eigens to calculate the square root?